# DIsplay content from a specific column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

First off I'm a total Rails newbie (front-end guy looking to learn rails), so bear with me.

I'm making a simple todo-ish app to help myself learn and have run into an issue. I'm assuming this is something super simple that I'm missing but here goes.

In my app users can create a number of "process_lists" (basically a list of tasks to complete). They also create "projects". Each project has a "process_list" associated with it. Process_lists are reusable, basically a set of steps to complete a project. One process list can be used for mnay projects. I've tagged the database table for projects with a column called "process_list_id" to help with associations. This is done when the user creates a project.

Now the code, this is whats in my projects controller:

```
   def show
@project = Project.find(params[:id])
@project_process = ProcessList.where(:id =>  @project.process_list_id)

respond_to do |format|
  format.html # show.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @project }
end
```

end

And in my view:

```
<%= @project_process.all %>
```

^^ This works great to display the whole row like so:

> ProcessList id: 6, name: "Derp Derp Derp Derp ", steps: nil, description: "lasdjlsdjsadas", created_at: "2012-06-22 16:21:41", updated_at: "2012-06-22 16:21:41", step1: "sjkdfldsjf", step2: "alkdfjdlfj", step3: "lakdfjdljf", step4: "", step5: "", step6: "", step7: "", step8: "", step9: "", step10: "", step11: nil, step12: nil, step13: nil, step14: nil, step15: nil, step1_description: "klsdjfldskjf", step2_description: "sldjfldskjflsdkfjdls", step3_description: "lkdsfjdlkfjsd", step4_description: "", step5_description: "", step6_description: "", step7_description: "", step8_description: "", step9_description: "", step10_description: "", step11_description: nil, step12_description: nil, step13_description: nil, step14_description: nil, step15_description: nil>

Now what I want to do is display certain columns from this row. For example "step1". It seems really simple but I've tried a number of thing and googled for hours now and I can't figure it out. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To directly answer your question:

```
<%= @project_process.first.step1 %>
```

This will print out the value of the `step1` column, "sjkdfldsjf" in your case.

If you have the line `has_one :process_list` in your class `Project`, then you can assign the `@project_process` variable much easier: `@process_list = @process.process_list`. You may also put `belongs_to :process` in the `ProcessList` class, so you have access to the process from the list object.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with previous answer, but If you want write nice Rails code, please read about associations between tables:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html

Also I dislike your ProcessList structure, it will seems better if you create else one table: "Steps" and connect table "Steps" and "ProcessLists" via associations.

Read about associations: has_many, has_one, has_many :through, belongs_to etc. It is really important.

Comment: Will definitely read it over, thanks! Any suggestions on resources to read to learn to better structure my database? Kind of assume it's the type of thing that I'll learn by doing it wrong =P

Comment: Clayton Correia, I don't read so special books, but if you are interested, my way of learning Rails was so:

1. Ruby - I got deep ruby knoledge, beause I suppose that it is really important to understand how it works.

Comment: 2. Rails Tutorial book - http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book, it is awesome book, it has nice example of app ( simple twitter ) which is developing during all book. And while I tried to read another books I want to develop my own example, but here I really like example and it fully captured my attention. After this book you can easy write nice, clean code. 
3. Rails Way 3, Docs, Api ...
Sorry for my poor English. Good Luck!

Comment: You're english is fine. Thanks very much for your help!